# IPython: Running commands asynchronously in the background

Tags: python, asynchronous, ipython

Say I have a **Python command or script** that I want to run from IPython asynchronously, in the background, during an IPython session.

I would like to invoke this command from my IPython session and be notified when it is done, or if something fails. I don't want this command to block my IPython prompt.

Are there any **IPython magics** that support this?  If not, what is the recommended way of running asynchronous jobs/scripts/commands (that run locally) on IPython?

For example, say I have a function:

```
def do_something():
   # This will take a long time
   # ....
   return "Done"
```

that I have in the current namespace. How I can I run it to the background and be notified when it is done?

Comment: Is it a standalone Python script (.py file) and not a function from currently imported modules? In that case you could just spawn a new OS process using Python subprocess module.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa It is Python code (commands and or scripts)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, try (in a cell):

```
%%script bash --bg --out script_out

sleep 10
echo hi!
```

The [script magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html) is documented along with the other IPython magics.  The necessary argument here is `-bg` to run the below script in the background (asynchronously) instead of the foreground (synchronously).

[GitHub Issue #844](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/844) is now resolved.

Comment: Could you add some explanation and for example link to a documentation, please?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy, this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, it's much better now, thank you. I didn't want it for me, but rather for others who will have the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

There used to be a magic function in iPython that would let you do just that:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Running-a-file-in-the-background

However, it seems that it was removed and is still pending to come back in newer versions:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/844

It still provides a library to help you achieve it, though:
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/api/generated/IPython.background_jobs.html

Answer (score 4):

The most general way would be to use the [Multiprocessing Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).  This should allow you to call functions in your current script in the background (completely new process).

***Edit***  This might not be the cleanest way, but should get the job done.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
ALONGTIME = 3

def do_something(mpPipe):
    # This will take a long time
    print "Do_Something_Started"
    time.sleep(ALONGTIME)
    print "Do_Something_Complete"
    mpPipe.send("Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=do_something, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    p.join() # block until the process is complete - this should be pushed to the end of your script / managed differently to keep it async :)
    print parent_conn.recv() # will tell you when its done.
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great pointer. I thought `multiprocessing` would help, I need to look into it, and it's great to have a specific simple example. What is the purpose of `p.join()` above? Do you know if the `%bg` magic in IPython was based on this module?

Comment: The p.join() blocks until the process is complete - not all the useful to your exact need, but required for the example.  You'll need to manage the connections some how to make sure you don't orphan your other processes.  I have used iPython in the past, but have no idea about that magic.